# PII checker with snowflake

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, pii

I am using PII checker lib for scanning pii data in snowflake database.
[https://github.com/tokern/piicatcher][1]](https://github.com/tokern/piicatcher%5D%5B1%5D)

but **scan_snowflake** function is internally creating url with postgreSQL
here is my code

```
catalog_params = {"app_dir": ":memory:"}
output = scan_snowflake(catalog_params=catalog_params, name="pii_db",
                        username={snowflake_username}, password={snowflake_password},
                        database={snowflake_database}, warehouse=args.warehouse,
                        role=args.role, account=args.account)
print(output)
```

Can anyone please tell how to get PII data of snowflake using PII catcher API?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is used from command line:

```
$ piicatcher scan snowflake [OPTIONS]
```

More details: https://tokern.io/docs/piicatcher/usage#piicatcher-scan-snowflake